# im trying to make a query on laravel but it's returning this error message

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to get all item series from a deposit but the deposit id is on a related table. On this function i'll list all the series between two sequences requested

```
public function getSeries($params = [])
{
    $data      = collect($params);
    $inicio    = $data->only('serie_in');
    $fim       = $data->only('serie_fi');
    $depOrigem = $data->only('id_origem');

    $series = [];

    for($i = $inicio; $i <= $fim; ++$i)
    {
        $item = Item::leftJoin('produtoItem', 'produtoItem.id', '=', 'item.id_produtoItem')->where('serie', $i)->where('produtoItem.id_deposito', $depOrigem)->first();

        if(empty($item))
        {
            $status = 'I';
        }
        else
        {
            $status = $item->status;

        }
        $series[] = [
            'serie' => $i,
            'status' => $status
        ];

    }
    $result = [
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $series
    ];
    return $result;
}
```

This is the error message, i'm thinking that must be as sintax error, but a dont realy know what? Can you help me?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: select * from `item` left join `produtoItem` on `produtoItem`.`id` = `item`.`id_produtoItem` where `serie` = ? limit 1) in file /usr/share/nginx/html/controleestoque/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671

Comment: Tip: Take the literal sql from the error(select * from `item` left join `produtoItem` on `produtoItem`.`id` = `item`.`id_produtoItem` where `serie` = ? limit 1) replace the questionmark with the actual value, and run it in a db tool. This will shed some light on what is going wrong. Once you understand what is wrong you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the request on my controller without a validator, so i rewrite the getSeries method.

```
public function getSeries(Request $request){
        $data = $request->only(['serie_in', 'serie_fi', 'id_origem']);
        $result = $this->produto_service->getSeries($data);
        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

And my function work it !